# Как можно сделать так

Tags: css, вёрстка

Пытаюсь сверстать на подобие этого.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv5w4.jpg
Получается такой .
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qL5A.jpg
  Как сделать размытие картин как на в первой ссылке ?

```
 <div class="slick-track">
    <il><a href=""><img src="src/assets/img/slaid3.jpg" alt=""></a></il>
    <il><a href=""><img src="src/assets/img/slaid4.jpg" alt=""></a></il>
    <il><a href=""><img src="src/assets/img/slaid5.jpg" alt=""></a></il>
</div>


.slick-track img {
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Comment: Сверстать как надо... Какие ещё варианты...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или можно сделать так

```
.slick-track {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50%;
 background-image: linear-gradient(blue 0%,blue 100%), url("a.png");
 background-blend-mode: color;
```

}

В градиенте задаете нужный цвет.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=background-blend-mode

Answer (score 2):

В примере не используется `blur()`, а просто такой фильтр... Это самый простой вариант...

```css
.slick-track {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 280px;
  background: url(https://s1.1zoom.ru/b5050/32/250997-frederika_1400x1050.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.filter {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
}
```

```html
<div class="slick-track">
  <div class="filter"></div>
</div>
```